# Usage of the various services in the docker-compose

Tags: docker

I understand that for running an archive node **only**, I don't need the other services defined in the `docker-compose` of the `scripts/alphanet.sh` script:

- `baker`, `endorser` and `accuser` are not required
- `importer` is not required if I don't importany snapshot
- `upgrader` is not more needed after the December upgrade

So I'll only run the `node` service, am i right ?

Thank you